# Вывод $_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookie

не могу понять почему cookie не выводится, в браузере в инфе страницы есть кука , при чем весьма с правильным содержимым (pass), а вот

```
var_dump($_COOKIE["pass"]);
```

мне всегда **NULL** выводит?

```
if ($user->createUser()){
     ob_start();
     setcookie('email',$user->email,time()+14400,'/');
     setcookie('pass','',time()-86400,'/');
     $form = $success;
    }
    else $form = $regform;

 break;

 case "goodluck": 
 /* Проверка соответсвия пароля */
 if ($user->checkPass($_COOKIE[email],$_POST["pass"])){

        ob_start();
        // установка куки пасс
        setcookie('pass',$_POST["pass"],time()+86400,'/');

        var_dump("cookie[pass]: ",$_COOKIE["pass"],"<br /><pre>");
        print_r($_COOKIE); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Пароль в куках? Нежелательно хранить даже хеши паролей не говоря уже о самих паролях...

Comment: да, погорячился, не стал этого делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ну здесь может быть несколько вариантов:**

1) Когда вы создавали куку, вы могли создать её, как "Pass", а прочитать из массива пытаетесь, как "pass". Регистр имеет значение!

2) Вы не обновили страницу после того, как создали куку. Массив `$_COOKIE` не обновляется динамически, как и любые другие переменные PHP.

3) Функция "var_dump()" возвращает информацию о переменной. Попробуйте просто вывести переменную в браузер или произвести отладочный вывод всего массива функцией `print_r()`. Затем посмотрите, присутствует ли переменная в массиве вообще.

Comment: в print_r($_COOKIE) она почему-то отсутствует, хотя в браузере я вижу.

Comment: добавлю кода, может так яснее картина будет видна, хотя...

Comment: Значит PHP её не загружает в массив кук. Это может быть, потому что в настройках( конфигурационном файле ) вашего веб-сервера( скорее всего это Apache ) отключен флаг чтения кукисов. Раскомментируйте эту строчку.

Comment: А, теперь стало ясно. У меня тоже недавно была похожая проблема!
Попробуйте создавать куку "Pass" не так: 
---
setcookie('pass','',time()-86400,'/');

---
а так:

---
setcookie('pass','none',time()-86400,'/');

---
Вместо "none" может быть любое значение длиннее 1 символа желательно.Мне это помогло.
Ведь кука "email" читается?

Comment: у меня в Apache нет ни строчки о кукис, я поиском [cookie]пробую, нет совпадений, но вот email четко выводит.

Comment: Для массива $_COOKIES пустое значение, как у вас в куке pass, считается за NULL.

Comment: я изменил логику, здесь уместно сессию использовать, спасибо!